# Using JavaScript within Power BI paginated reports

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-paginated-reports

Is there a way of using JavaScript  within a Power BI paginated report published to the Power BI service? My company are looking into migrating all of our SSRS reports to within the Power BI service.

None of the the things we use JavaScript for are particularly fancy, mainly for larger scale tooltips or opening external links with parameters. I know this is possible through the action - go to URL/go to report options but a best case scenario would be continuing using the existing JavaScript from the SSRS reports as they are functionally the same RDL file but tweaked.

I spent most of this afternoon trying to get the existing JavaScript to work but i’m at a total loss as to where to go next!

Tried a variety of different ways of calling the JS, within Action - using Placeholders etc but nothing i’ve tried seems to work!